# Url generator for start URLs scrapy (only reads first URL), why?

Tags: python, class, url, scrapy

I am using scrapy as webscraping framework and scraping a number of different domains for a set of companies. I have generated a URL-generator class, which reads a file with companies and generates a start URL for the companies on different webpages(only one example company shown). The web scraper runs fine for the first record, but it does not run for the other URLs. I have tested the URL-generator and it returns all URLs, but for some reason this does not work start_urls = [start_url.company-site()]. Any ideas?

URL generator file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os 
import os.path

class URL(object):
    P=[]

    def read(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                field = line.split(',')
                company = field[1].replace(" ", '+')
                adress="{0}+{1}".format(field[5],field[11])
                self.P.append("http://www.companywebpage.com/market-search?q={0}".format(company))

    def company-site(self):
        for i in self.P:
            return i
```

Spider file

```
root = os.getcwd()
start_url = URL()
p = os.path.join(root, 'Company_Lists', 'Test_of_company.csv')
start_url.read(p)

class company-spider(BaseSpider):
    name = "Company-page"
    allowed_domains = ["CompanyDomain.se"]
    start_urls = [start_url.company-site()]
```

Comment: I'm not sure its valid to use a `-` character in the name of a class/function, I get `SyntaxError`s in both python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
def company-site(self):
    for i in self.P:
        return i
```

with

```
def urls(self):
    for url in self.P:
        yield url
```

Replace

```
start_urls = [start_url.company-site()]
```

with

```
start_urls = start_url.urls()
```

or

```
start_urls = start_url.P
```

Because `Spider.start_requests` looks like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
```

Comment: It works with adding the yield and remove the [] brackets. Thanks!

Comment: as you are new here, please consider accepting and/or upvoting helpful answers

Comment: I can't. I need more points. What is the best way to get 15 points, so I can at least upvote?

Comment: I upvoted you question. When you get enough points you can accept unaccepted answers. You can get points if your questions and answers are upvoted being good.

Comment: Thanks, I will up vote you answer as soon as I get enough credits.